# Using Distributions for classification

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions

My question is very naive so please bear with me. (And it's been probably asked before but I may not know the correct keywords.)

Imagine I have a quantity $Q$ associated with each member of a population and this population is a priori divided into two subgroups $A,B$ . I'm interested to see if my quantity can tell to which subgroup a given member of the population belongs.

So I compute the quantity for all members of the population. (Assuming this is possible). If the distributions of $Q$ for the two subgroups do not overlap then it is easy to formulate a hypothesis as a member with a given $Q$ must belong to $A$ or $B$.

If the distributions of $Q$ for the two subgroups overlap but are significantly different (in a non-technical sense) then how can one formulate a hypothesis that relates the value of $Q$ for a member to the subgroup to which it belongs?

Then after formulating the hypothesis how can one test it for accuracy?

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem of [classification](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification).
You can essentially do:
\begin{align}
\Pr(A \mid Q) &= \frac{\Pr(Q \mid A) P(A)}{P(Q)} \\
\Pr(B \mid Q) &= \frac{\Pr(Q \mid B) P(B)}{P(Q)} \\
\frac{\Pr(A \mid Q)}{\Pr(B \mid Q)} &= \frac{\Pr(Q \mid A)}{\Pr(Q \mid B)} \times \frac{\Pr(A)}{\Pr(B)}
,\end{align}
so that you can look at the ratio of the probability (density) of $Q$ for each of the two classes and compare it to the ratio of the  overall sizes of the subsets to determine which subgroup is more likely.

Now, the way you actually estimate those probabilities from data is a large area that depends on your problem at hand. The problem of confidence in your classification is naturally given by the probability of membership.